# Clean or convert pdf documents

Tags: fonts, pdf, text

I have a pdf file (500 pages) with a lot of images ( black and white). However, the text is blurred and although it is readable, it's really a pain ( maybe hardcopy was scanned poorly, not sure on that).

Is there some way I can 'clean' the pdf file ? I can manage with diagrams in the present quality because they are big and so I'm ok. But the text is not manageable. So ideally, I would like to create a replica but with good text quality.

I can't really use some convertors because there are images in the pdf file (and that too plenty in no).

Using ubuntu 14.04.

I'm not a dev. Just a normal user.

Update:

I would again like to emphasise that pdf file has a lot of images as well, and text is blurred badly. Unfortunately, gscan2pdf didn't work at all.

Comment: Is possible to make a sample? Is possible to improve the quality of pdf but is necessary a lot of work. Is good but for words. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjjogfWfWsQ

Answer (score 1):

You should try using gscan2pdf, One of my mates was using it recently and said it was good and made the font readable.

Here's a link for the same : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gscan2pdf/

Comment: Nope. That didnt work. I Tried 'clean' option with the pdf as well as OCR. Both didnt work.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: That's irrelevant, because the link doesn't try to provide instructions but a piece of software.

Comment: @Siddarth: Please explain, how to use gscan2pdf to “clean” scanned images (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).